# Finding Green's Functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Well, I'm trying to understand how to find Green's functions for differential operators, and I'm working on the problem $Lu=-u''$ with BC's $u'(0)=u(1)=0$.  Can someone tell me if I'm doing this correctly?  In the end, I am getting that the Green's function is defined as $g(x)=(1-t)H(t-x)+(1-x)H(x-t)$ where $H(x-t)$ is the heaviside function.  Basically, the main idea is to make the function continuous at x = t and satisfy the derivative jump discontinuity, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct as far as I can tell.  That said, I have no idea what you did to get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main idea is to satisfy the equation $$-g''=\delta_t\tag{1}$$ The fact that Green's function is continuous is something special to your one-dimensional situation; don't get too used to it. In higher dimensions, Green's functions for the Laplacian are unbounded near $t$.

Recalling that $\delta_t$ is the (distributional) derivative of $H(x-t)$, we integrate (1) to get
$$-g'(x) = H(x-t)+A\tag{2}$$
for some constant $A$. Integrate (2) again: 
$$-g(x) = (x-t)^+ +Ax +B \tag{3}$$
where $(\cdot )^+ = \max(0,\cdot)$. It remains to find $A$ and $B$ to satisfy the boundary conditions. Plug $x=0$ into (2) to get 
$$ 0 = 0 +A$$
hence $A=0$. Plug $x=1$ into (3) to get 
$$0 = 1-t +B $$
hence $B=t-1$.

Rewrite (3) with this new information: $-g(x) = (x-t)^++t-1$, or 
$$g(x)=1-t-(x-t)^+ \tag{4}$$
I find (4) easier to parse than the formula in your post. Also, (4) makes it clear that $g$ is  (Lipschitz) continuous, which is not immediate from your formula involving discontinuous $H$.

Comment: This is an old answer, but can anyone argue to be why the Green function in higher dimensions is unbounded "near t"?